# What are these symbols and abbreviations "CP, IP, Ti, Ap" called?

Tags: syntax, terminology

[image: symbols]

I want to know what are these abbreviations existed in the picture referring to, and want their names to read about?

" cp, ip, ti, ap, ...etc"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are the names of standard constituents in X' (X-bar) notation:

- CP - Complementizer Phrase ... *This particular flavor of X' theory treats the 'fronted' auxiliary as a CP. I don't much care for the name, but the notion that any clause has a 'complementizer' which plays much the same role as a Determiner in a Noun Phrase can be useful.*
- IP - Inflection Phrase ... *This is the 'root' of a predicate, the constituent which bears inflection for tense and agreement.*
- *t<sub>i</sub>* - Trace, co-indexed by the subscript <sub>i</sub> with the fronted auxiliary ... *This is the 'gap' left behind when the auxiliary 'moves' out of the IP into the CP position.*

  This particular version, with the duplicated trace, is unfamiliar to me. If anybody wants to chip in and explain it, please do!
- VP - Verb Phrase ... *A constituent composed of a verb and its dependents*.
- AP - Adjective Phrase ... *A constituent composed of an adjective and its dependents.*

I have no idea why *Mary* isn't labeled as an NP (which is sort of like a Noun Phrase except different). Perhaps your source is stripping out labels that don't bear on whatever point is being treated immediately.

The bracket notation is a space-saving way of recording syntactic structure; you can plug it into a tree drawer (without the duplicate *t<sub>i</sub>*)and get this:

[image]

Scores of books have been written about this approach to syntactic analysis; if it interests you there are very good sites

- [here](http://amyrey.web.unc.edu/classes/ling-101-online/tutorials/) by the teacher of an Intro to Linguistics class at the University of North Carolina. Look at the sections Understanding X-bar Structure, Drawing Sentence Syntax Trees and Drawing Question Syntax Trees ...
- and [here](http://allthingslinguistic.com/post/100357884082/how-to-draw-syntax-trees-part-1-so-you-asked), from a linguistics blog.